# Защита от повторного включения заголовка

Tags: c

В проекте на C, код которого я недавно стал смотреть, используется защита от повторного включения заголовка:

```
#ifndef H_HEADER
#define H_HEADER

// Header itself

#endif
```

Для унаследованного кода (где все и так работает), это нормально. Но для новых исходников хотелось бы что-нибудь проще.

Есть ли аналог/заменитель в C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C есть специальная директива

```
#pragma once
```

которая указывает компилятору, что заголовок должен быть включен только один раз.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, #pragma once - это специфика Microsoft VC++, следовательно в Unix мире не может быть использована.

Comment: #pragma once не входит в стандарт C и не все компиляторы ее поддерживают; полностью портируемый код должен избегать ее. Тем не менее, GCC поддерживает эту директиву, поэтому и на Unix она доступна.